# BOOST min-cut/max-flow on undirected graph with source and target

Tags: c++, boost, max-flow, lemon-graph-library

Can I use any algorithms from Boost on an undirected graph which must have a source and target (two nodes which must be in separate cuts).  The preflow_relabel says it requires a directed graph.   Stoer_wagner_min_cut says it works on undirected graphs but I can't find where it asks for a source/target node.

If not, anyone have any recomendations?  I setup Lemon to work but I think they do max flow on an undirected graph by treating it as two directed edges one going each way.  This causes runtime issues where the runtime is tied to the magnitude of the capacity of some edges.

And this is for University level computational biology research, I say this as I assume people might otherwise ask why we want source/target for undirected graph with max-flow/min-cut.

Thanks in adance.